# XML feed won't parse

Tags: xml, rss, google-apps-script

I have an xml feed that, for some reason, will not parse for me:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzX9FOtXLjTH5_ZFPMPaSRDwDmGPJAJ2SkTYgRN_eVjtfbfy7yf/exec?template=S14069818285u14068754955&download=false

Would anybody have any idea whats wrong with this feed?

**Background:**

- It's pulling in each of the `<`item`>` data from a Google Drive Spreadsheet OK.
- It validates OK, and shows in Chrome browser (but not Firefox)
- I ultimately need this xml feed to work via my private CMS, but I know if I - or anyone - can get the
  feed working OK in Google Reader/ Feedly / etc then I'll be in business.
- Neither the above address nor the script.googleusercontent.com address that it resolves to in the browser will work for me in a feed reader.
- Note that I can modify the header or footer of the xml file if needs
  be

MANY thanks for any input on this very frustrating issue!, cheers, Dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say it doesn't "parse" I assume you mean that the browsers are not displaying it as an RSS feed, right?

If that is the case, the problem is the Content-Type (in the response header) returned by your script.  RSS feeds are XML files and the Content-Type type should be application/xml, you are currently returning text/html.

Comment: Thanks @crash - this looks like it might be the issue. The feed validates now via the W3C validation service. Can I ask how do you check and then modify the content-type?